# Google cloud cleanup policy is not applied on the artifact registry

Tags: gcloud

I have a repository called staging, with this cleanup policy:

```
gcloud artifacts repositories list-cleanup-policies staging

Listing items under project XXX, location us-east1, repository staging.

Dry run is disabled.
[
  {
    "action": {
      "type": "KEEP"
    },
    "mostRecentVersions": {
      "keepCount": 20
    },
    "name": "keeplast20images"
  }
]
```

Its been two weeks since I have set this policy but the number of tags per repository is growing and seems none of them getting deleted (some images have more than 100 tags)

I tried this command to get the audit logs but it doesn't have any output:

```
gcloud logging read 'protoPayload.serviceName="artifactregistry.googleapis.com" AND protoPayload.request.parent="projects/XXX/locations/us-east1/repositories/staging" AND protoPayload.request.validateOnly=true' \
    --resource-names="projects/XXX" \
    --project=XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

We got this kind of problem as well, at least we didn't see the audit logs.

A permission on Artifact Registry should be missing. You should have read and write rights on audit logs to see the new ones.